# Controll Motor Driver HAT Waveshare with C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, i2c

I am very new in this. So if anyone can help will be great. I am trying to control Motor Driver HAT Waveshare with `C#` via `i2c` from my `Raspberry pi 4b`. I Install `Iot.Device.MotorHat` NuGet package and try this example but the result is  `Unexpected value of duty cycle (9766, 10280)`.

[image]

This is the i2c addres

[image]

This is my class

```
using Iot.Device.MotorHat;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Device.I2c;

namespace projectV2
{
    public class DCMotorController : BaseClass
    {
        public void StartMotor()
        {
            using (var motorHat = new MotorHat(200, 0x40))
            {
                var motor = motorHat.CreateDCMotor(1);

                motor.Speed = 1;
            }
        }

        public void StopMotor()
        {
            using (var motorHat = new MotorHat(200, 0x40))
            {
                var motor = motorHat.CreateDCMotor(1);

                motor.Speed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use **0x80** as an I2C address? Some libraries mistakenly want 8-bit address, while it’s actually 7-bit.

Comment: I try 0x80 , but nothing happend, now i fix the code a litle bit now i take error ```Unexpected value of duty cycle (9766, 10280)```